# Create one plot visualization for each field value

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-5

I see that I can split a chart on a field (e. g. "Website"). However, since I have too many field values, it becomes unreadable and I want to have a separate chart for each. Can I achieve that with Kibana, Kibana Plugins or anything similar without having to create a visualization for each value?

Comment: Do you want to create visualisation for each value? For example for Amazon website one visualisation and for yahoo website second?

Comment: Yes. If I'd have 50 websites, I'd have 50 visualizations. It would be useful to just scroll through it and see if anything crashed lately.

Comment: What about using table visualisation, table is good to use when you have a lot of values. I don't think that create so much visualisation, when each visualisation contain one bucket(value) is good idea